# How to use a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function written in JavaScript. The function is correct, I cannot change it. I need to write HTML code to handle it. Unfortunately, I do not fully understand how it works, when starting the debugger it screams errors:

```js
function A2(params) {
  if ((params / (10 % 4)) === 132.993) {
    var m = document.querySelector("Math");
    console.log("A2 hip hip hura");
    m.innerHTML = "Set Text In Here :";
    var arr = [m];
    arr.push("Element");
    arr.push("Second Element");
    m.addEventListener("click", A2(arr));
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Math">
  <input type="text" value="nothing" />
</div>

<input type="submit" value="SEND" onclick="A2(265.986)" />
```

*error:*
TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Comment: try `var m = document.querySelector("#Math");` (note the `#` which refer to an id)

Comment: Your queryselector is missing a "#" infront of "Math" and therefore returning undefined. Adding a hashtag should do the trick. You should have a selector like "#Math".

Comment: If you cannot change the Javascript, there's no way to make it work using whatever HTML you come up with.

Comment: Additionally, even if the selector will be fixed, the line `m.addEventListener("click", A2(arr));` won't work, nothing will happen when `m` is clicked, since `A2` doesn't return a function.

Comment: Go back to whomever told you it was correct and tell them you've found a few errors. It is possible to add a Math element <Math ...></Math> to your HTML but this is unlikely and not expected.

Comment: @phuzi I thought too, that adding a Math element would work, but `document.querySelector` [doesn't seem to find it](https://jsfiddle.net/yf6om1t9/).

Comment: @Teemu Your fiddle seems to work for me and `m.innerHTML` updates  the element's content. I'm using Chrome Version 98.0.4758.102 on Windows 11. Perhaps behaviour is not that well defined and differs between browsers.

Comment: @phuzi OK, I'm on Firefox and Win10. I would had expect Math tag to work in Firefox as well. It has specifically something to do with `<Math>`, as `<muth>` works.

Comment: Looks like you lost the OP.

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev Who? Me and phuzi? Don't you find the comments being quite relevant to the post? Phuzi has suggested a working solution, and I said the suggested solution doesn't work in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use the querySelector according to the [right selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
which is # in that case

```html
<html>  
<head>  
<script type = "text/javascript">  
function A2(params) {
    if ((params / (10 % 4)) === 132.993) {
        var m = document.querySelector("#Math");
        console.log(m)
        console.log("A2 hip hip hura");
        m.innerHTML = "Set Text In Here :";
        var arr = [m];
        arr.push("Element");
        arr.push("Second Element");
        m.addEventListener("click", A2(arr));
    }
}
</script>  
</head>  
<body>  
<div id="Math">
    <input type="text" value="nothing" />
</div>

<input type="submit" value="SEND" onclick="A2(265.986)"/>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing happens when you click "Set Text In Here :" text.

Comment: This seems to work for me. @Teemu perhaps Firefox's issue with "Math" goes beyond element names!

Comment: @phuzi Maybe you've misunderstood my comment, I meant that the event listener attached inside the function doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What you forgot is just `#` sign before `Math`.
Use `var m = document.querySelector("#Math");` instead of `var m = document.querySelector("Math");`
In addition, be sure to read these:

[Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

[CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Here, a little example, just run code snippet:

```js
function A2(params) {
    if ((params / (10 % 4)) === 132.993) {
        var m = document.querySelector("#Math");
        console.log("Responding!");
        m.innerHTML = "Button is pressed:";
    }
}
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
}

.button {border-radius: 5px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Math">
    <input type="text" value="nothing" />
</div>

<input type="submit" class="button" value="SEND" onclick="A2(265.986)">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing happens when you click "Button is pressed:" text.

Comment: @Teemu, sorry, does the question cover that as well?

Comment: There's no question in the post, but in general you should fix all the errors if you're going to answer.

Comment: @Teemu, you're totally right! Unless he edits the question, I'm just removing that part of the code.